# How can I get the contents of all elements with a specific parent class in jQuery and pass them in a GET variable?

Tags: javascript, ajax, arrays, jquery

I need to collect the contents of all list items with the parent class of `list_array`, then pass them via a GET variable to an AJAX call.  Can you recommend a strategy?

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXKzV/).

HTML:

```
<div>
    <ul class="list_array">
        <li>item A</li>
        <li>item B</li>
        <li>item C</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>some text</p>
<div>
    <ul class="list_array">
        <li>item B</li>
        <li>item C</li>
        <li>item D</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<p>some text</p>
<div>
    <ul class="list_array">
        <li>item A</li>
        <li>item C</li>
        <li>item E</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my current progress:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var listItemArr = [];
    $('.list_array li').each(function() {
        listItemArr.push($(this).text());
    });
    alert(listItemArr);
});
```

​
As the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXKzV/) shows, this doesn't work.

Ideally I would just pass unique strings as well, so the expected result would be:

```
item A
item B
item C
item D
item E
```

(and not contain the duplicates)

Also, any recommendation in passing the array to my PHP processing page is welcomed.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a sidenote: I updated your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VXKzV/1/). You left to import jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = [];
$('.list_array li').each(function() {
    var t = $(this).text();
    if (arr.indexOf(t) === -1) {
        arr.push(t)
    }
})
// arr = arr.join(',')  
// =>  item A,item B,item C,item D,item E
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4eRHF/2/)**

You can use the jQuery **`$.post`** or **`$.ajax`** utility functions for sending the data to PHP:

1. **[$.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)**
2. **[$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)**
3. **[$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)**

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about PHP. Here is the client side code:

```
var arrayName = 'whatever';
//use an object as an SET to remove duplicated items
var dict = {};
$('.list_array li').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
}).each(function(){
    dict[this] = '';
});
//retrieve the values saved to the SET
var params = '';
for(var k in dict)
    params += arrayName + '=' + k +'&';
//send request
$.get('/path/to/your.php', params, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    //or do what ever you want with the response.
}, 'html');
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var all=[];
$('ul.list_array li').each(function(){
    var text=$(this).text();
    if($.inArray(text, all)==-1) all.push(text);
});
$.get('/url/to/page', {'items': all}, function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

variable `all` is an array like `["item A", "item B", "item C", "item D", "item E"]` and your array is available in `$_GET` as `$_GET['items']`.

[Check this to see the filtered array](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/bsnGM/1/).